# Igmp snooping based multicast forwarding

Tags: switch, multicast, igmp

In Igmp snooping switch receives an Igmp leave report? Is it possible to change the timeout value in Igmp snooping switch?

Comment: Hi, this question is pretty unclear because it's missing context.  Is this a theoretical question or are you trying to solve a problem?  If you're solving a problem, then please tell us what problem you're solving.  If this is a theoretical question then please add more details about why you're asking it.

Comment: I need snooping switch timers function?

Comment: I still don't understand what you need... please review [this link about IGMP timers](http://blog.ine.com/2008/10/31/a-quick-overview-of-basic-igmp-timers/) and let us know if you still have questions...

Comment: Mike, he is talking about setting timers in the switch and not on individual hosts that send IGMP reports. I am going to edit the questions a little bit.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

We should be able to configure member leave time in the switch.

For Cisco boxes, we can configured this timer globally or on a vlan-basis: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12.2/50sg/configuration/guide/multi.html#wp1126514 .

```
##To configure globally
ip igmp snooping last-member-query-interval time 

##To configure on a per-vlan basis:
ip igmp snooping vlan vlan_ID last-member-query-interval time
```

Juniper boxes also support this feature: http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos/topics/task/configuration/igmp-snooping-ex-series-cli.html

I would recommend doing some more Google.

Comment: Please quote the relevant parts of those referenced documents. So when those URls break, your answer would still make sense.

Comment: Fair point. I have added the relevant config.